# updating data in firebase without overwriting previous data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data into firebase but every time I execute the code to save the data, the previous data is being overwritten in firebase. I have tried to follow a few tips on here, but I have not been able to succeed.

```
 fileprivate func saveSwipeToDataBase(didLike: Any) {
    let swipeDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    guard let cardUID = topCardView?.cardViewModel.uid else { return }

    let documentData = ["userSwipeId": uid,
                        "didLike": didLike,
                        "checked": 0,
                        "Swipe Date": swipeDate,
                        "type": SWIPE_INT_VALUE] as [String : Any]

    self.postJobDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: cardUID, values: documentData as [String : AnyObject])

}
private func postJobDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://oddjobs-b131f.firebaseio.com/")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let usersReference = ref.child("UserSwipes").child(uid)
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print("error saving data into firebase")
            return
        }

    })
 }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

I feel as if the issue is with the updateChildValues but I am probably way off. thanks for any and all of the help.

Comment: Do you want to save data as a new entry? if yes then why you are using updateChildValues?

Comment: @Neeraj yes I would like to save new data as a new entry! I have been looking this up but I can't find out how to make the changes

Comment: @Neeraj do you know of a better method?

Comment: Try this as user reference:- 
let usersReference = ref.child("UserSwipes").child(uid).childByAutoId().key else { return }

Comment: I'm met with more errors Value of type 'String?' has no member 'updateChildValues' at the line usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print("error saving data into firebase")
                return
            }
            
        })

Comment: Please clear your requirement so I can help you in a better way

Comment: ok try this
let usersReference = ref.child("UserSwipes").child(uid).childByAutoId()

Comment: sorry? what do you need me to do?

Comment: Is this solution worked?

Comment: @Neeraj it kind of works, but it is saving a bunch of autoUid instead of one. like 10 different saves

Comment: so do you need only one entry?

Comment: yes, just one entry but previously it was overwriting previous data instead of adding a new line. for example, say you have two users trying to save data. when I save data for one user, it saves. when I save data for another user, it overwrites the previous saved data instead of adding its seperate save

Comment: Then your previous code should work fine

Comment: It over writes every saved data with the next user instead of adding an additional block of code

Comment: have you checked  uid? is it different for both user or getting same id for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new child node to a location with an autogenerated (and guaranteed to be unique) ID, you'll want to call `childByAutoId()` on  that location.

So to add a new chid node under `/UserSwipes/$uid` when `postJobDataIntoDatabaseWithUID` is called

```
private func postJobDataIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://oddjobs-b131f.firebaseio.com/")
    let usersReference = ref.child("UserSwipes").child(uid)
    usersReference.childByAutoId().setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print("error saving data into firebase")
            return
        }
    })
 }, withCancel: nil)
```

Changes from your version:

- This no longer adds an observer, which isn't needed since your new data doesn't depend on any existing data.
- This now calls `childByAutoId()` to generate a new child node.
- This then calls `setValue()` to set the value of the new child node.
- The function is called `postJobDataIntoDatabaseWithUID`, fixing a typo you had in the original.